# Зачем нужна ссылка на конструктор?

Tags: java, конструктор

Для чего? Зачем писать

```
ClassName::new
```

Для чего это вообще может использоваться?

И каким боком там функциональный интерфейс? Вообще связи не вижу((

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObHdS.png  (ссылка на ориг https://habr.com/ru/post/216431/)

Comment: Чтобы передать в какой-то другой метод, например. `И каким боком там функциональный интерфейс?` - любая ссылка на метод или конструктор реализует функциональный интерфейс.

Comment: Я читал эту статью, но вообще не понял. Допустим, есть функциональный интерфейс, с 1 методом который необходимо реализовать. Ну ок, я создал класс "Dog" и реализовал метод функ. интерфейса и теперь собачка у меня говорит "Гав".  Ок, я пошёл дальше и сделал через лямбда, очень красиво и кратко. Только вопрос так и остался, каких боком там ссылка на конструктор и зачем она?

Comment: И Паттерны мы не проходили, я примерно знаю что такое фабрика, но только примерно.(

Comment: Приведите пример кода, сейчас не понятно, что конкретно вы сделали очень красиво и кратко, и каким боком там ссылка на конструктор.

Comment: Звучит так Создайте класс Calculator. (создал) В нем создайте статическую переменную типа Supplier. (Создал) Это функциональный интерфейс, реализующий метод get(). С помощью данной переменной можно будет получить экземпляр класса Calculator. (Нет, я не могу получить объект класса Calculator по этой ссылке) Реализуйте ссылку на вызов конструктора класса Calculator( Зачем? Что мне это даст, почему я просто не могу создать объект?) { }.

static Supplier<Calculator> instance = Calculator::new; И что мне это дало? Это не объект, и использовать instance  я нигде не могу, это же не объект

Comment: См. мой первый комментарий. Вы можете передать эту ссылку в какой-то другой метод, который уже внутри себя вызовет конструктор, таким образом создав объект. Это примерно как спрашивать про лямбду: вот у меня есть лямбда, но какой в ней смысл, если я могу точно так же написать отдельный метод.

Comment: Кажется вы читаете что-то для более продвинутого уровня, а ваш - новичковый. Видимо вы ещё не сталкивались со стримами, делегатами и подобными вычислениями. Вот ссылки на методы (а конструктор - это тоже метод) именно для таких целей. И создать объект вполне можно будет, например  `list.forEach(Calculator::new);` (точнее там вызов конструктора, но по сути это будет одновременно и создание объекта)

Comment: Да, если честно я не понимаю что такое стримы,а слово делегат слышу впервые( Это будем проходить только на следующем занятии https://s.mail.ru/gz7W/gLwbFc7Qv и Ваш код я тоже не понимаю (((, если откровенно

Comment: Вот вам надо дойти до темы Лямбды, И тогда станет чуточку понятнее.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-colon-operator-in-java/